# How to commit using Scm-Manager web interface

Tags: svn, scmmanager

I have configured scm-manager, and able to create a new SVN repository in it. But there is no option for importing data into it. I would appreciate you, if you could help on this.

Comment: Try to do it commandline. Best way to learn version control...

Answer (score 0):

SCM Manager is a server for your source code repositories. It doesn't provide client functionality through it's web application.

You need a Subversion client to commit your files to the Subversion repository. Your IDE may include such client or you use a standalone client like [TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net) if you're under Windows or the command line tools which are available for all OS.

Answer (score 0):

For SCM-Manager 2 the editor plugin can be installed, which allows editing through the web interface.